# What do these notices mean?

Tags: log

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av9qC.png)
This is my log from orbot. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's trying to fetch information from https://onionoo.torproject.org/ about the relays (I assume over it's own copy of Polipo) and since Polipo is trying to use Tor, which hasn't bootstrapped yet.

It hasn't bootstrapped because you've specified a limited set of reachable ports or addresses in the Orbot settings, and you have configured it to use bridges, but none of the bridges are available on the required ports or address ranges.

You need to either find bridges that are available on the required ports or addresses, using https://bridges.torproject.org/ or unrestrict the accessible ports and addresses to allow Tor to reach it's chosen bridge(s).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm gonna check it out. Let ya know if I got it going.